# Can I access GCS from html in django's html?

Tags: javascript, html, django, google-cloud-storage

I want to read and visualize the pdb file saved in GCS in ngl viewer.

The code to read a file in ngl viewer is as follows.

```
function go(){
            stage.removeAllComponents()
            var pdb = document.getElementById('id_pdbid').value
            var path = "rcsb://" + pdb
            stage.loadFile(path, {defaultRepresentation: true})
        }
```

Here you can simply change the url to something like https://storage.cloud.google.com/example-storage-bucket/folder/example.pdb, but it will cause CORS issues.

So I want to access GCS from the script itself in html. (not using url)

Is there a way to access it in html, javascript as well as using python's GCS library?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCS allows you to change [CORS settings](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors) so that your original method of directly getting the URL will work.

Comment: I did fix it by applying CORS as per your advice. However, the above question has not been solved... I will try again in the future and leave the results.

Comment: This part was unavoidably corrected using URL, and it does not appear to be a CORS problem.